# I need to disable checkboxes in a Wordpress Plugin named UsersInsight written in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a Plugin called UsersInsight installed and activated in a Wordpress site. There is a button named "Toggle Column" which when clicked opens a drop down box with checkboxes and custom field name of Subscribers, wherein one can view all the personal details of the Subscribers. I need to disable the fields so that the personal details of my Subscribers are not visible.

I do not know Angular and even then i tried to find out the code from the files but could not.

```
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="field in showFields" ng-class="{'usin-sortable' : field.order !== false}">
            <span ng-if="field.id=='username' && userList.users.length" class="usin-heading-checkbox">
                <md-checkbox aria-label="Select All"
                            ng-checked="bulkActions.isAllChecked()"
                            md-indeterminate="bulkActions.isAllIndeterminate()"
                            ng-click="bulkActions.toggleAll()"
                            class="usin-toggler-checkbox">
                </md-checkbox>
                <md-tooltip md-direction="top">{{bulkActions.isAllChecked() ? strings.clearSelection: strings.selectAllUsers}}</md-tooltip>
            </span>
            <span ng-click="setOrderBy(field.id)">
                <span class="usin-heading-{{field.id}}">{{field.name}}</span>
                <span class="usin-order-arrow" ng-class="{'usin-order-arrow-up' : userList.order == 'ASC', 'usin-order-arrow-down': userList.order == 'DESC'}"
                    ng-show="userList.orderBy==field.id"></span>
            </span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="user in userList.users">
    <td ng-repeat="field in showFields" ng-switch="field.id" title="{{field.name}} ({{user.username}})" class="usin-field-{{field.id}}">
        <span ng-switch-when="username" class="usin-username-clickable usin-username-wrap">
            <span class="usin-online-circle" ng-if="user.online" title="{{strings.online}}"></span>
            <span class="user-avatar-actions">
                <span ng-bind-html="user.avatar" class="usin-avatar-wrap"></span>
                <md-checkbox ng-checked="bulkActions.isChecked(user.ID)" ng-click="bulkActions.toggle(user.ID)" 
                    aria-label="Select User" md-no-ink="true"></md-checkbox>
            </span>
            <a class="usin-username" ng-href="#/user/{{user.ID}}">{{user.username}}</a>
        </span>
```

I could not understand the code as i don't know Angular.